# How is &nbsp; supposed to be rendered in Wingdings?

Tags: html, fonts, cross-browser

I noticed that in Chrome and IE (not Firefox) `&nbsp;` renders as a dot when the font-family is set to Wingdings. Is this expected or is this a rendering bug? Also, any ideas why firefox doesn't render it the same way?

Example: http://codr.io/v/zhs4f42

Edit: The only happens in Chrome 40 and IE. Chrome <= 39 and Firefox show an empty space.

Comment: is Wingdings a custom font? I entered the example and I just see an empty space. Chrome version 39

Comment: No, but it may be a Windows font? Not sure. I am seeing it in Chrome 40 on two different Windows machines.

Comment: I'm on a MacBook Pro for the moment, and as I told before, I really don't see any dot. Anyways, I tried to play with firebug, and Wingdings are all symbols.

Comment: Ok. I just tried it in browserstack and the dot only appears in Chrome 40 and IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NO-BREAK SPACE (which is what `&nbsp;` means) is not expected to be rendered in the Wingdings font at all, because that font (which is specific to Windows) does not contain a glyph for that character. Thus, when `font-family: Wingdings` is set and the text contains a NO-BREAK SPACE, the browser should take a glyph from some fallback font or just leave a space.

What some browsers do, as incorrect behavior, is that they use the glyph that happens to reside in Wingdings in position A0 (hexadecimal), corresponding to Unicode code number of NO-BREAK SPACE. This is wrong because Wingdings is not a Unicode-encoded font; it just has a private assigment of glyphs to positions.

According to a [Wingdings to Unicode mapping table](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html), that glyph represents the Unicode character U+25AA BLACK SMALL SQUARE “▪”. In a small font size, it may look like a dot.